# Open Screen from TabView Flutter not Fullscreen

Tags: tabs, flutter, navigator

I have a view as attach files

[image: First Screen With Tabs]

```
body: TabBarView(
controller: _tabController,
children: [
    TabSreen(index: _tabController.index, eventId: widget.eventEntity.eventId),
    TabScreen(index: _tabController.index, eventId: widget.eventEntity.eventId)
    ]
),
```

TabScreen is StatefulWiget,
Click on each item in List of TabScreen, open to SecondScreen

[image: Second Screen]

How to make the second screen show as fullscreen. I mean the SecondView should remove the part: Event1, Event Name, Status. Just showing the view with below navigation as Fullscreen

Currently, I am using following code to open the SecondScreen (StatefulWiget) from TabScreen

```
Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new SecondScreen(title: _forms[index].name)),
    );
```

Comment: please share some code.

Comment: @Mertus I have just updated code

Comment: have you got any solution?? i have same problem like this@BaDo

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example since you didn't share enough code, you can compare your code with this.

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primaryColor: Color(0xFF048ec8),
        indicatorColor: Colors.red,
        cursorColor: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: MainScreenWithTab(),
    );
  }
}

class MainScreenWithTab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MainScreenWithTabState();
}

class MainScreenWithTabState extends State<MainScreenWithTab> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Screen'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TabBar(
              tabs: <Widget>[
                Tab(
                  text: 'Left',
                ),
                Tab(
                  text: 'Right',
                )
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(children: [
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Tap for new screen'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Screen()));
                  },
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text('Push View 2'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Screen()));
                  },
                ),
              ]),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Screen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Screen'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.yellow,
        child: Center(
          child: Text('New Screen'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Navigator.of(context,rootNavigator: true)
         .push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => PDFScreen(path: pathPDF.path),
            ),
          );
```

You should allow the screen a new navigator, try the above code, it should work now.